# Could not resolve placeholder in two spring xml context

Tags: spring, jasypt

I have two Spring xml context as below :

mail-config.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <constructor-arg ref="strongEncryptor"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:mailconfig.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and

applicationContext.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath*:mail-config.xml"/>
<bean id="strongEncryptor"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES"/>
    <property name="password" value="...."/>
    <property name="poolSize" value="4"/>
</bean>
```

When all beans are in one xml file, everything is Ok. but when I separate them as above, I have got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'host' in string value "${host}"`

`Edit :`

Full stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'host' in string value "${host}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
```

Comment: Can you show `mailconfig.properties` and the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @Jens the mailconfig is just a simple key value file as others

Comment: And it contains the property `host`?

Comment: @Jens Yes! it contains

Comment: Where it is located?

Comment: @Jens in the resources path. When I merged the xml contexts, everything was fine

Comment: Can you post your properties file?

Comment: Also, do you have another property placeholder configurer defined somewhere else in your spring context?

Comment: @ConMan Yes I've defined another in the applicationContext.xml

Comment: Please can you show me what your full applicationContext.xml looks like?  I think I might be able to explain this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `Bean` to load your `Properties` file

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="......OpenPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/mailconfig.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

the class OpenPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer :

```
public class OpenPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer implements
        IPropertiesHolder {

    private Properties properties;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see 
     *      #getProperties()
     */
    public Properties getProperties() throws IOException {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = mergeProperties();
        }
        return properties;
    }

}
```

the interface IPropertiesHolder :

```
public interface IPropertiesHolder {

    /**
     * Get the Spring declared properties
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Properties getProperties() throws IOException;

}
```